# What exactly does a closure do when retrieving data from a server?

Tags: swift, closures, nsurl

I watched a video on closures and someone demonstrated the basics of closures in this way:

```
func outer(howMuch: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var total = 0

    inner() {
        howMuch += total
        return total
    }
return inner
}
```

He then went on to say that when you do this:

```
let incrementBy10 = outer(10)
```

he said that incrementBy10 references the inner() function inside the closure.

Then he proceeds with a practical example with retrieving data:

```
let url = "*url here*"
let nsURL = NSURLSession.shareSession().dataTaskWithUrl(nsURL) {(data,response,error) in 
print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)) }
```

How does the 'incrementby10' example relate to the practical example of fetching some data from a server. I did not understand what he meant by: "when you grab something from a url, you are not gonna have the content immediately. You can call the closure when the url has been downloaded."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of an *asynchronous callback*.

Asynchronous callbacks are used to execute a closure when a long-running operation (e.g. a network request) has finished. They allow us to fire the network request, passing in the callback, then continuing executing other code while the network operation is in progress. Only when the operation finishes, the closure is executed, with the data returned by the server passed in as an argument.

If we didn't use asynchronous closures, when we fetch something from the server, the app would freeze (execution would stop). This would be a synchronous network request, and it is not used as it would lead to a very laggy UI and a horrible user experience.

`NSURLSession`'s `dataTaskWithURL` is by nature an asynchronous API, it accepts a closure as an argument and fires it when a response is received.

---

### Asynchronous Callback

Example of an asynchronous callback network call (add it to a Swift Playground):

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground // Only needed for Playground

// Only needed for Playground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class HTTP {

    class func GET(onSuccess: NSData -> Void ) {

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            onSuccess(data!)

        }).resume()
    }
}


print("About to fire request")
HTTP.GET({ payload in
    let response = NSString(data: payload, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("Got network response: \(response)")
})
print("Just fired request")
```

The result that is printed is not what you might expect intuitively:

```
About to fire request
Just fired request
Got network response: ...
```

`Just fired request` is printed *before* `Got network response: ...` because the network request is performed asynchronously.

A synchronous version of the above code would produce the following output:

```
About to fire request
Got network response: ...
Just fired request
```